# Play console not showing any information to enter when filling App content's Ads

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

**Screenshot:**

You can see I am not able to do anything here, is this a bug or am I missing something to fill before coming to this page?

[image]

Other screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interestingly when I click on [learn more](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9773697#ads) link in 1st screenshot, it says 'Sorry this page can't be found`, I think Google removed this feature from their system but forgot to do on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to google developer support, they told me to turn off adblock.  I did that and refreshed and was able to see the content on the page successfully.  Hope that's the same thing you're dealing with here.

Comment: Wow, really, I didn't know that, thank you so much for putting efforts, I'm accepting your answer for now (without confirming it)